# Table row (tr) separation and border

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a styling issue with tables.

I need the following:

- responsive tables (on mobile some cells collapse)
- separation between table rows
- border between table rows
- can't assume anything about table row height

Something like this:

image:

[image]

for reference check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m15rccmr/

```css
table{
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0 30px;
}
tr{
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

.mobile-fold{
    display:block;
}
@media (min-width: 800px){
    .mobile-fold{
        display:table-cell;
    }
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
           <tr>
            <td>first</td>
            <td class="mobile-fold">second</td>
            <td class="mobile-fold">third</td>
       </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td>first</td>
            <td class="mobile-fold">second</td>
            <td class="mobile-fold">third</td>
       </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td>first</td>
            <td class="mobile-fold">second</td>
            <td class="mobile-fold">third</td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I need to add a border between the table rows, and it should display fine on mobile and desktop.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are after

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/m15rccmr/2/)

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0 30px;
}
td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
td:nth-of-type(2) {
  border: none;
}
.mobile-fold {
  display: block;
}
@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .mobile-fold {
    display: table-cell;
  }
  td:nth-of-type(2) {
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>first</td>
      <td class="mobile-fold">second</td>
      <td class="mobile-fold">third</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>first</td>
      <td class="mobile-fold">second</td>
      <td class="mobile-fold">third</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>first</td>
      <td class="mobile-fold">second</td>
      <td class="mobile-fold">third</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. however, I need the red line to be in the middle of the rows. like a separator. also I cant assume only 3 tds, perhaps there are more.

Comment: You'd have to provide an image of what it is you are after. This was just an example...

Comment: Done, cant upload the full image but that should be enought to get an idea. thanks!